# Route 53 aws www.domain.com works but domain.com not

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, hosting, amazon-route53

**I created load balancer for my ssl certificate, created hosting zone, created two records and changed name servers on my domain provider.**

Now it's.

Records:
[image]

I tried to do domain.com ----> load balancer but this not worked.
I changed this few hours ago, do i need to wait more time or change something?

with domain.com i get This site cannot be reached error

Domain.com gives
[image]

Comment: When you say doesn't work are the referring to resolution? Have you tried  running DIG to evaluate both sets of records resolutions?

Comment: What is " (another record)"? Since you are using R53, can you provide exact record types that you used.

Comment: @Marcin i posted screenshot of my records

Comment: It seems to all work for me as expected. Can you check by clearing up your caches in browser or in private mode?

Comment: @Marcin i tried in incognito and it's still same (second image on my post)

Comment: Maybe its something on your local workstation that blocks it. It works in browser as I [screenshoted](https://i.imgur.com/O7d2L8i.png).

Comment: @Marcin oh that's weird sometimes it's work sometimes not

Comment: Maybe DNS is not fully propagated.

Comment: @Marcin so what can i do with this, what does that mean

Comment: The domain is also bought using R53?

Comment: @Marcin no it's from another domain provider but i changed name servers on it to server names from records

Comment: I think you could wait a bit more and check again later. Then if nothing helps, maybe its issue on the domain provider side? Difficult to speculate.

Comment: Just wonder how did it go? The issue still persists?

Comment: @Marcin it's work now. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Glad to hear that. If you don't mind I will provide an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The domain, when tested by me, was working fine. The issue for OP was resolved after waiting a bit. The reason it did not work at first could be that DNS changes were not fully propagated or old DNS was cached for longer than expected.